# How do you make a throw-away database with mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for the equivalent of:

```
pg_ctl init -D ~/throw-away-database
pg_ctl start -D ~/throw-away-database
……… work work ………
pg_ctl stop -D ~/throw-away-database
rm -rf ~/throw-away-database
```

in MySQL Community server 5.7.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_install_db --datadir=/tmp/foo
mysqld_safe --datadir=/tmp/foo --socket=/tmp/foo/mysql.sock
mysql -S /tmp/foo/mysql.sock -u root -p
set password = password('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
……… work work ………
killall mysqld
rm -rf /tmp/foo
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
create schema my_throw_away001; -- creates a database synonym schema
use my_throw_away001; -- set this as the current to use

-- Do stuff like

create table myTable
(  id int auto_increment primary key,
   thing varchar(100) not null
);

insert myTable(thing) values ('frog'),('cat');

select * from myTable;

-- Cleanup:

drop schema my_throw_away001; -- drops database, poof gone
```

Comment: I don't see where to specify where the data are stored.